# How to Share a Leaflet Map Instance Across Multiple Vue 2 Components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

**Background:**
I'm building a web application using Vue 2 and Leaflet. I'm trying to share a single Leaflet map instance across multiple components in my application.

**Issue:**
I'm looking for a way to create a Leaflet map instance in one place and access and use it across multiple components in the entire application.

**Code Example:**
This is a method I have tried, but I don't know if this way of writing is appropriate. Maybe there is a better way:

App.vue

```
  provide() {
    return {
      parent: this
    };
  },
  mounted() {
 this.map = L.map('map',{})
}
```

components

```
 inject: ["parent"]
```

Is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: pretty sure provide/inject was made for the use case you're describing. Do you have an issue with it? Though, not sure I'd provide `this`, perhaps provide `map`

Comment: Providing "this" is a bad practice, provide data on per need basis. Provide composition ref() or just plain { value: ... } object if you don't use the recent Vue 2 version

Answer (score -1):

Your approach using Vue's provide/inject mechanism can work for sharing the Leaflet map instance across multiple components. However, there might be a more elegant and maintainable solution, especially as your application grows. One such solution involves using a dedicated service to manage the Leaflet map instance.

This is an example of how you can create a service to manage leaflet across many devices:

1. Create a `LeafletService.js` to handle the creation and management of the Leaflet map instance:

```js
import L from 'leaflet';

class LeafletService {
  constructor() {
    this.map = null;
  }

  createMap(mapElementId, options) {
    if (!this.map) {
      this.map = L.map(mapElementId, options);
      // Additional initialization or configuration can be done here
    }
    return this.map;
  }

  getMap() {
    return this.map;
  }
}

export default new LeafletService();
```

2. In your App.vue, you can create the map instance during the application initialization phase.

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Your other components -->
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LeafletService from './services/LeafletService';

export default {
  mounted() {
    // Create the Leaflet map instance in the App.vue
    LeafletService.createMap('map', {});
  },
};
</script>
```

In other components where you need access to the map, you can import the `LeafletService` and use `getMap()` to access the map instance.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Your component content -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LeafletService from '../services/LeafletService';

export default {
  mounted() {
    // Access the Leaflet map instance from the service
    const map = LeafletService.getMap();
    // Use the map instance as needed
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: AI-generated answers are disallowed on SO. This is a piece of unnecessary convoluted code